# How to assert if I have specific unique values in a subdictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

```
dictionary = {'key01' : {'value_a': 1, 'value_b': 4, 'value_c': 1, 'value_d': 1},
            'key02' : {'value_a': 2, 'value_b': 5, 'value_c': 2, 'value_d': 6},
            'key03' : {'value_a': 3, 'value_b': 6, 'value_c': 2, 'value_d': 9}}
```

Each `value_a` must be unique in comparison with other `value_a`.
Each `value_b` must be unique in comparison with other `value_b`.
Each `value_c` must be unique in comparison with other `value_c`.
etc...

I.e. if `dictionary['key01']['value_a']` is 1, this value CAN'T appear again in `dictionary['key02']['value_a']` and `dictionary['key03']['value_a']`.

I need to write a **pytest-assert** for that!

In the example, there's a error since `dictionary['key02']['value_c']` and `dictionary['key03']['value_c']` are equal.

Comment: In other words, it needs to be in one line? The best way is to use a function due to its complexity but it can still be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
dictionary = { 'key01': { 'value_a': 1, 'value_b': 4, 'value_c': 1, 'value_d': 1 },
               'key02': { 'value_a': 2, 'value_b': 5, 'value_c': 2, 'value_d': 6 },
               'key03': { 'value_a': 3, 'value_b': 6, 'value_c': 2, 'value_d': 9 } }

for key_first, key_second in itertools.combinations(dictionary, 2):
    for internal_key in dictionary[key_first].keys():
        if internal_key not in dictionary[key_second]:
            continue
        assert dictionary[key_first][internal_key] != dictionary[key_second][internal_key], \
            "Values in dictionary should be unique for the same keys!\n" + \
            "Invalid keys are " + key_first + " and " + key_second + "\n" + \
            "for values of " + internal_key
```

It might be confusing at first, but what it does is:

1. go through every key in the dictionary and compare it's value with every other keys value (but not with itself),
2. compare values of all of the keys in the internal dictionary if they are present in both of them,
3. if for any key the values are equal, throw AssertionError.

You can wrap that solution in a function by adding in the beggining:

```
def test_unique_values(dictionary: dict):
```

Comment: Great solution, @Jezor! But it'd only work with a dict of 3 keys, right?

Comment: Nope, it will work with any number of keys. Notice that there is no `3` magic number anywhere in the code. If you'd like to check only specific keys in internal dictionaries, please update your question and add that requirement to it.

Comment: A simpler loop that would halve the work and remove the `if ...` check would be ... `for k1, k2 in itertools.combinations(dictionary, 2): ...`

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I updated my answer. I'm fairly new to Python so I'm not familiar with all of the utilities yet (;

Answer (score 2):

Lets generalise it and assume that the subdictionaries may contain different keys.  Then lets find the distinct keys (eg `value_1`, `value_2`, ...) across all of the values in `dictionary`

```
value_keys = set.union(*(set(v) for v in dictionary.values()))
```

Now for each value key, how many sub dictionaries contain it?  That's how many distinct values we will hope to see for that key:

```
counts = {k: len([sub_dict for sub_dict in dictionary.values()]) 
          for k in value_keys}
```

Now find the actual number of distinct values for each value key among the dictionaries

```
distinct_counts = {k: len({sub_dict[k] 
                          for sub_dict in dictionary.values() 
                          if k in sub_dict}) 
                   for k in value_keys}
```

Compare them to find the incorrect ones:

```
errors = {k for k, v in distinct_counts.items() if v != counts[k]}
```

Now check if errors is empty.

```
>>> print(errors)
{'value_c'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the dictionary to a data frame and then check the unique values of each row for which we can check if the length of the row and the size of the unique values `(set(row))` are the same, if not, throw an exception:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)

df
#           key01 key02 key03
# value_a     1     2     3
# value_b     4     5     6
# value_c     1     2     2
# value_d     1     6     9

def test(row):
    if row.size != len(set(row)):
        raise Exception("Test Failed!")

res = df.apply(test, axis = 1)
```

This will throw an exception of failed test.

Comment: It's returning a "fixture 'row' not found" though.

Comment: It depends on what data you actually have. This solution works for the data you posted. By which I mean, for example, do all the sub dictionaries have same keys? As that will affect the data frame construction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super long list comprehension I came up with:

```
assrt( False not in [[False if list(set([dictionary[k][val] for k in  [key for key in dictionary.keys()]])) != [dictionary[k][val] for k in  [key for key in dictionary.keys()]] else True] for val in dictionary["key01"].keys()])
```

Which would be clearer:

```
for val in dictionary["key01"].keys():
    d = [dictionary[k][val] for k in  [key for key in dictionary.keys()]]
    assert(list(set(d)) == d)
```

`d` gets all the values and puts them together (e.g. `value_a` in `key01`, `key02`...), then, it tests if the unique list is equal to the current list.